# Getting notification when bounded/unbounded to a HTTP session

Tags: session, servlets, notifications

How can i get notified when my Object gets bounded/unbounded to a session object of HTTP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let the object's class implement [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html).

```
public class YourObject implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        // The current instance has been bound to the HttpSession.
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        // The current instance has been unbound from the HttpSession.
    }

}
```

If you have no control over the object's class code and thus you can't change its code, then an alternative is to implement [`HttpSessionAttributeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html).

```
@WebListener
public class YourObjectSessionAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if (event.getValue() instanceof YourObject) {
            // An instance of YourObject has been bound to the session.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if (event.getValue() instanceof YourObject) {
            // An instance of YourObject has been unbound from the session.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if (event.getValue() instanceof YourObject) {
            // An instance of YourObject has been replaced in the session.
        }
    }

}
```

Note: when you're still on Servlet 2.5 or older, replace `@WebListener` by a `<listener>` configuration entry  in `web.xml`.